# How to include a variable used in function in same/others files Java netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, serial-port

I want to open and close serial port in two different functions. and I'm getting an error while closing serial port: cannot find symbol serialPort. those two functions are in the same file.
what do I have to do to resolve the problem ?

```java
private void openSerialPortActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        Object selectedItem_port = availablePortBox.getSelectedItem();// for selected port 
        SerialPort serialPort = new SerialPort((String) selectedItem_port);
...
        try {
            serialPort.openPort();//Open serial port
            serialPort.setParams(serialBaud, 
                                 serialData,
                                 serialStopBit,
                                 serialParity);//
         }
...


}// openSerialPortActionPerformed

private void closeSerialPortActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        serialPort.closePort();
    } //closeSerialPortActionPerformed
```

Comment: where did the `availablePortBox` came into picture from? Use that place to declare `serialPort` as well.

Comment: Make a private field in this class instead of defining it in method openSerialPortActionPerformed

Comment: Instead of declaring `SerialPort serialPort` in your method you can declare it on a class level. And during the method `openSerialPortActionPerformed()` you can initialize it. I think that should solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare the variable `serialPort` outside the method.

Comment: It worked. what if I want to use `serialPort`in an other file but, in the same project ?